# Angular components and & binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

My code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/components/appComponent.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
   <foo callback="$ctrl.myCallback()"></foo>   
</body>

</html>
```

appComponent.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.component('foo', {

    bindings: {
      callback: '&'
     },

    templateUrl: '/js/components/appComponent.html',
    controller: function () {
      this.callback=function(){
        console.log('Hello!');
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

appComponent.html

```
<div ng-click="$ctrl.myCallback()">
  Press me!
</div>
```

**Why ng-click does not trigger $ctrl.callback()?** Moreover, what `callback="$ctrl.myCallback()"` is supposed to do? I am afraid I have misunderstood its concept.

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  you don't have a controller in your html body, so how could `$ctrl.myCallback()` reference anything?

Comment: I thought $ctrl refers to the controller inside the directive. Could you please explain to me a little bit more where it refers to? Thank you

Comment: in a template, it refers to the controller that is loaded along with the template.  *outside* the template, (in the `<foo>` tag in this example) it doesn't seem to refer to anything.

Comment: the purpose of `&` inside the `bindings` is to designate that the component is going to be passed a function that is declared outside the component, and call that function instead of a function declared inside the component.

Comment: in your example, you have a function named `callback` but you don't seem to have a function named `myCallback` anywhere.

Comment: So that means that if I do not have outer controller, bindings are useless?

Comment: not entirely, but for this scenario, yes.  you could still use one of the other binding types to pass a string value to the component without an outer controller, for example...

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations.Please allow me a last question: is it possible to unit test a component if it does not have bindings?

Comment: bindings aren't a requirement for Unit Testing;  They would be necessary for testing *interactions*, but if you don't have bindings, you have no interaction.  You can still test other features, like rendering, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136044/discussion-between-ilias-and-claies).